# Illusive evap code - Hard to find the issue

Tags: honda, emissions, diagnostics, evap, diagnose

98 Honda Civic Ex. For a while now my car will throw a p1456 evap code but sometimes it doesn't and the system completes the test.

I'll randomly hook up my obd2 scanner and it'll either have a pending code for p1456 or not.

It seems to pass the test if outside ambient temps are 70F or higher. If it's colder out I'll most likely see the code come up.

Paid a shop to run a smoke machine through it but there were no obvious leaks. As per suggestions I've replaced the two way valve and bypass valve but didn't make a difference.

12v on both the vent and purge valves gets them to activate.

My car doesn't need to pass emissions since it's older than 15 years but I don't like having the check engine light on all the time.

Things replaced: Gas cap, filler neck, bypass and two-way valve

Edit: Pic of the sending unit area [image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I find it somewhat interesting that you didn't mention the gas cap at all, i.e. have you replaced it? Have you even considered it as the cause?

Comment: @juhist Just edited and included things I've replaced. Gas cap was first one

Comment: Have you checked the seal on the sending unit? It's fairly common for the tank to rust and cause a poor seal around the sending unit. This may or may not show up on a smoke test depending on how bad it is.

Comment: @Ben I have not. Would this explain why in hotter ambient temps the evap tests pass? (Seal expanding?) Still trying to use that little clue to help pin point the problem

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess, based on the information. I don't remember if there is an sending unit access port on these Civics but it's worth taking a look.

Comment: @Ben yeah there is under the seat. Just looked and there's definitely surface rust. Looks little scary removing the bolts due to the rust. Will I know visually if the seal is bad or need to run smoke test again? Also I just included a pic of the sending unit area in original post. Which access port would it be? Wasn't expecting to find two

Comment: Unless it's visibly cracked it'd be hard to say. You'd have to be able to feel it see if it's hardened. If the bolts won't come out without breaking try cleaning around the seal with a wire brush and use some black RTV. See if the code comes back.

Comment: @Ben I was thinking of trying that with some form of sealant to see what would happen. Any other type besides the black RTV that fuel vapors wouldn't affect?

Comment: Not really, it's just a temporary seal to see if the sender seal is leaking. You could try finding this part number "0783 830 2120" It's a sealant used for a Stihl chainsaw apparently. Regarding the two unit's I'd guess one is for the pump and the other for the level sensor or it's a split tank with two sending units. Either one could be leaking.